# Mask the last two digits of a date in JavaScript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I’m trying to demonstrate how a date would look like if it was displayed with some characters masked. Specifically, something like this:

- 10 August 2018 => 10 August 20**
- 10 August 2018 => 10 August **** (and this too if possible)

I’ve spent some time looking for working examples on here but haven’t found one for this specific example. In my own experiments I only ever end up with one asterisk (10 August 19*) instead of one per character.

It all needs to happen within a `textToMask.replace(regex, '*')`.

I know you’d never use this in production; it’s for a visual demo.

Comment: What is the code you’ve tried?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you masking the end part of a date?

Comment: Hey, @Jhecht, I'm looking to obscure personal/private information, in this case a person's date of birth, when displayed on a screen. This could be shown for example on a kiosk where you might not want someone seeing your full DoB.

I'm looking for a solution I can use within the constraints of a replace() within an interactive prototype that has a function I can call to mask different types of info e.g. show only last three digits or section of a phone number, domain of an e-mail address etc.

Comment: @Xufox, there are so many different examples on here but I've never found one that works. Also spent lots of time on RegExr but for some reason I can only get the last two as a group? e.g. `/\d{2}$/g` returns a single * in my `.replace(/\d{2}$/g,"*")` :(

Comment: @ctrlaltdelete for that last example you could just use double asterisks, or use the function variant of `.replace()` where you use a function as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `padEnd` method

```js
function maskIt(str, pad = 1) {
  const slicedStr = str.slice(0,pad*-1);
  const masked = slicedStr.padEnd(str.length, '*');
  console.log(masked);
}
maskIt("10 August 2018",2);
maskIt("10 August 2018",4);
```

Comment: Nice alternative. It even works if `pad` > the string length.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is great. Sadly I'm stuck within a .replace in the prototyping environment I'm using. I'm looking for a single function I can call and eventually build out with additional case statements to switch out the regex for different ones depending on the type of data I'm masking. Regex is a dark art or I'd have used something like your solution.

Comment: You will not require any Ajax after it. Just pass a parameter (`String`, `character to be mask`) and you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dirt simple `mask()` function, that works with any string, and doesn't involve regex:

```js
function mask(str, amt = 1) {
  if (amt > str.length) {
    return '*'.repeat(str.length);
  } else {
    return str.substr(0, str.length-amt) + '*'.repeat(amt);
  }
}

console.log(mask('10 August 2018', 2));
console.log(mask('10 August 2018', 4));
console.log(mask('test', 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple function that uses a regular expression to find a given number of digits at the end of a given date and substitutes them with an equal number of asterisks.

**Example:**

```js
const mask_date = (date, n) => date.replace(new RegExp(`[\\d]{${n}}$`), "*".repeat(n));

console.log(mask_date("10 August 2018", 2));
console.log(mask_date("10 August 2018", 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I would really like to refactor this somehow, I just don't have the time to do it right now. Check back at some point tomorrow I may have made an edit to this to make the code flow a bit better.

I am using the second version of the [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function that allows you to pass a function instead of a string as the second parameter. Check the link to learn more.

This is a very rough function -- I unfortunately did not have a lot of time to write this out.

```js
// str - string to be altered, pattern - regex pattern to look through, replacement - what to replace the found pattern with, match_length - do we match the length of replacement to the length of what it is replacing?
function mask(str, pattern, replacement="*", match_length=true){
  
   return str.replace(pattern, function(whole, group){
    
    //init some values;
    let padLength = 0, returned = '';
    
    // if the group is not a number, then we have a regex that has a grouping. I would recommend limiting your regex patterns to ONE group, unless you edit this.
    if(typeof group != 'number'){
      padLength = group.length;
      returned  = whole.slice(0, whole.indexOf(group)) + (replacement.repeat(match_length ? padLength : 1));
    }else{
      padLength = whole.length;
      returned = replacement.repeat(match_length ? padLength : 1);
    }
    return returned;
  });
  
}

let randomBirthdayString = 'April 3 2002';

console.log(mask(randomBirthdayString, /\d{2}(\d{2})$/) );
console.log(mask(randomBirthdayString, /\d{2}(\d{2})$/, 'x') );
console.log(mask(randomBirthdayString, /\d{2}(\d{2})$/, 'x', false) );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below.

`textToMask.replace(/..$/, '**')`